# How can I consume and autocomplete a field from url that contents json information

Tags: php, json, autocomplete

I'm trying to autocomplete a field from url that contents json information, I find a lot of examples that I dont know where is my error.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
   $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://camino-rest-service.cloudhub.io/caminoAPI/GetCamino",
            data: { query: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                var transformed = $.map(data, function (el) {
                    return {
                        label: el.ubicaciones
                    };
                });
                response(transformed);
            },
            error: function () {
                response([]);
            }
        });
    });
});
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

JSON example

```
  [
    {
      "ubicaciones": "San Gabriel, Provincia de Carchi"
    },
    {
      "ubicaciones": "El Ángel, Provincia de Carchi"
    },
    {
      "ubicaciones": "Ambuquí, Provincia de Imbabura"
    }
  ]
```

some could says who is my error? I try everthing that I know

Comment: I believe one issue is the format of your JSON. It can either be an array of strings, or an array of objects with the properties `label` and `value`. But yours does not comply to either. check here: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: you  need to add data type as Json  `dataType: "json"`

Comment: Is there any error when executing it? Or why are you asking us for the error?

Comment: I can't see the information when I try to autocomplete

Comment: Link you provide  did not respond to  any post or get method and there is syntax issue.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( function() {
   $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
            url: "http://camino-rest-service.cloudhub.io/caminoAPI/GetCamino",
              
        dataType: "json",
           
            success: function (data) {
                var transformed = $.map(data, function (el) {
                    return {
                        label: el
                    };
                });
                response(transformed);
            },
            error: function () {
                response([]);
            }
        });
    }
});
  });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

you  have syntax error in  code and  link you provide is nor respond to  **POST** or **GET** method  **(i fix only syntax issue)**

Comment: Hi, Lakmal the thing is that i generate that service with mule. Do you know how could I do a get link to comsume the information?

Comment: @ChristianAbata Is that link  data change time to time?

Comment: Yes the final result that I need is connect 2 application using mule, and consuming 2 services. For example if I nodify the data from camino-rest-service I need to see that change in the other aplication.